# How to add a CC recipient to existing CC recipients?

Tags: vba, outlook

The code below overwrites the existing recipients in the CC field.

Is there any way to add example@domain.com to the end?

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents oExpl As Explorer
Private WithEvents oItem As MailItem
Private bDiscardEvents As Boolean

Dim oResponse As MailItem
Dim WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Dim WithEvents objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer

'On Reply All
Private Sub oItem_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    bDiscardEvents = True
    Set oResponse = oItem.ReplyAll

    afterReply
End Sub

Private Sub afterReply()
    oResponse.Display
    ' do whatever here with .to, .cc, .cci, .subject, .HTMLBody, .Attachements.Add, etc.
    oResponse.CC = "example@domain.com"
End Sub
```

EDIT: Thanks to @ProfoundlyOblivious my code now looks like this but example@domain is showing up in the CC twice (and three times if they were in the CC to begin with, probably the fact it shows their display name might be the issue for the latter)

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents oExpl As Explorer
Private WithEvents oItem As MailItem
Private bDiscardEvents As Boolean
Dim oResponse As MailItem
Dim WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Dim WithEvents objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_handler
    Set oExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer
    bDiscardEvents = False
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set objInspectors = Application.Inspectors
    Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set objMailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
        If objMailItem.Sent = False Then
            Call SetFromAddress(objMailItem)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

'The next 3 lines to enable Outlook 2013/2016/365 Reading Pane Reply
Private Sub myOlExp_InlineResponse(ByVal objItem As Object)
    Call SetFromAddress(objItem)
End Sub

Public Sub SetFromAddress(oMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    ' Set your preferred default From address below.
    ' Exchange permissions determine if it is actually stamped
    ' as "Sent On Behalf Of" or "Sent As".
    ' The address is not properly updated for the InlineResponse
    ' feature in Outlook 2013/2016/365. This is only a visual bug.
    oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "example@domain.com"
    oMail.CC = "example@domain.com"
End Sub

Private Sub oExpl_SelectionChange()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oItem = oExpl.Selection.item(1)
End Sub

'on Reply
Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    bDiscardEvents = True

    Set oResponse = oItem.Reply
    afterReply
End Sub

'on Forward
Private Sub oItem_Forward(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    bDiscardEvents = True

    Set oResponse = oItem.Forward

    afterReply
End Sub

'On Reply All
Private Sub oItem_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    bDiscardEvents = True

    Set oResponse = oItem.ReplyAll

    afterReply
End Sub

Private Sub afterReply()
    oResponse.Display

    If oResponse.CC Like "example@domain.com" Then
        oResponse.CC = oResponse.CC
    Else
        oResponse.CC = oResponse.CC & "; example@domain.com"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `oResponse.CC = oResponse.CC & IIF(Len(oResponse.CC)=0, "", ";") & "example@domain.com"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:  `oResponse.CC =  oResponse.CC & "; example@domain.com"`

If the email doesn't have any CC recipients then this answer will create a superfluous semicolon and space "; example@domain.com".  I am pretty sure Outlook well ignore it but you may want to check out the example provided David Zemens in the comments if it causes a problem.

Important Note: [MailItem.CC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.cc) only references CC display names, my answer is not a substitute for [Recipients.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.add).

Comment: That worked flawlessly, thank you!! I will post the final code as reference later today

Comment: I test your solution in almost all scenarios (no one in CC, 1 person in CC, multiple people in CC) and it works just fine. My issue right now is integrating that with my overall script (also if I should be bringing this up in a new question, do let me know). I will post it as an answer as I don't have enough room in this comment

Comment: If you need help implementing the answer with the code you provided in the question then I'll help you here.  If you have a different script that was not not part of the question, then a new question is appropriate.

Comment: Please see edit in the original question. I've integrated your part into it near the bottom

Comment: I think this would best be addressed with a new question. 
 Regarding the display name, `oResponse.CC` is only for the display name.  If you want to work with the recipient email address as CC then you would use `Recipients`.  You can read about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.cc

Comment: Don't do that - CC is not guaranteed to contain email addresses, only display names, and you can get an error when the names are resolved again and you have an ambiguous name. Add a CC recipient using Recipients.Add

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the `CC` property - even if you append to it, CC is not guaranteed to contain email addresses, only display names, and you can get an error when the names are resolved again and you have an ambiguous name.

Add a CC recipient using `Recipients.Add`:

```
set recip = oMail.Recipients.Add("example@domain.com")
recip.Type = olCC
```

Comment: good point, I mentioned this in the comments but it belongs as part of the answer.  Will update.